# What does mean the icon in the projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I work with the Visual Studio 2019 (ver. 16.5.1), and suddenly a weird icon appeared in my projects:

[image]

I'm not really sure what the icon means, it seems to be a box or something similar.

What does the icon mean exactly? Is there something broken in my solution?

Comment: What happens, when you expand the projects?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the project tree is expanded, the files seems to be ok but the cs files have the same icon. I've run some tests and the solution is working well

Comment: What source control (if any) are you using for this solution?

Comment: @MichaelMurray Perforce has been added to the solution as version controller, it explains everything, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments in both, question and the Efthymios's answer, I was able to know that this icon (star or box, still unclear what it is) is related to the Perfoce Control Version that was added to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is broken in your Visual Studio. Probably they added icons to beautify the display of the projects in your solution.
If I am not mistaken:

1. the first icon in the picture is a C# project,
2. the second one is probably a web project (maybe ASP.net)
3. and the third one is a test project

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the kind of the project and its icons, I'm asking about the weird white and red box in the left side of the project icon

Comment: I don't know about the star but usually on the left are icons of the Version Control system showing some status (eg. Git).